# Remove chapter spacing completely

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, titlesec

In the below MWE, I arranged the position of the chapter title (for this case I just need the number) such that it is at the corner touching the margin. How do I remove the spacing created around it completely, such that the text begins at the place as if there is no chapter entry at all?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  [block]% shape
  {\filcenter\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{\thechapter}}% before the title body
  \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\newcommand{\maketitleframe}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=5pc, yshift=-2.5pc, xshift=2.5pc] at (current page.north west) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}% before the title body
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also change the `\titlespacing` of `\chapter`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  [block]% shape
  {}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{\thechapter}}% before the title body
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{-2\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\maketitleframe}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=5pc, yshift=-2.5pc, xshift=2.5pc] at (current page.north west) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}% before the title body
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
test
\end{document}
```

[image: one page]

But, if you just want the number and also no running head and no ToC entry, you could simply just place the `tikzpicture` without using `\chapter`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\chapternum}{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=5pc, yshift=-2.5pc, xshift=2.5pc] at (current page.north west) {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\chapternum
test
\end{document}
```

or with ToC entry and running head:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\chapternum}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=5pc, yshift=-2.5pc, xshift=2.5pc] at (current page.north west) {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapternum{}
test
\chapternum{ToC Entry and Head}
test
\clearpage
test
\clearpage
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `-2\baselineskip` is how the spacing defined, so we are removing it, or should it be customized case by case?

Comment: AFAIK `titlesec` always prints the title, even if it is empty. The `-2\baselineskip` just moves back to the position before the title. This is one reason, why I've also told how to avoid printing a title if your don't want a title. See my second and third example.