# Shifting the "Contents" heading to ensure that the distance between the top of the paper and the "Contents" heading is 2.5cm

Tags: table-of-contents, geometry, titletoc

In this minimum working example, I am trying to shift the "Contents" heading to ensure that the distance between the top of the paper and the "Contents" heading is 2.5cm. I want to do the same for list of tables and figures but I have not had my way around it. Trying {\vpsace{-2.5cm} \tableofcontents} has no effect. I will be grateful if anyone can help me out.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter}
{\filcenter\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\bfseries
\ \justwords{\thechapter}}
{1ex}
{\vspace*{5ex}\filcenter\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\bfseries}
\def\justwords#1{\ifcase#1 \or CHAPTER ONE\or CHAPTER TWO\or CHAPTER THREE\or CHAPTER FOUR\or CHAPTER FIVE\or CHAPTER SIX \fi}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3.7cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,  top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709200/277964 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708827/277964

Comment: BTW: You should not use `\thechapter` but `\value{chapter}` as an argument of `\justwords`, because `\thechapter` could be something like `A`, `IV`, `17.` etc.